# How to get facebook user info along with post info using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I am trying to fetch visitor posts from a Facebook page using Facebook Graph API.
For more info see this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed

According to documentation, I am using this: `**/{page-id}/tagged?fields=message,id,created_time,from**` to fetch the public posts in which the page has been tagged.

I am also fetching the user info using "**from**" field.

I am able to get the post array. Here is the sample response.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "message": "Sample message text...",
            "id": "136617136381867_1041817205861851",
            "created_time": "2016-01-28T12:13:37+0000",
            "from": {
                "name": "Annu Chelladurai",
                "id": "10152476225064109"
            }
        }
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

I am able to get the user id and user name under "from" key.

How can i get other user info fields like "**picture**", etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got it..
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#fields

We can use nested requests, as explained in the above document.

So the request is modified as `**/tagged?fields=id, created_time, message, from{id, name, picture, location }**`

And it works like a charm. It give me the user info and picture url also.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "136617136381867_1042310465812525",
            "created_time": "2016-01-29T08:14:32+0000",
            "message": "Dear Sir,

            \ "77000002 TERM DEBIT CARD ADJ 18-01-16\" Can you explain why this charge?And Deduction happend more than 30 times
            I am having HDFC Salary a / c 01331610161892,
            in my account Rs11 .24 is
            charged 30 times as\ "77000002 TERM DEBIT CARD ADJ 18-01-16\" with same description. What is this with out any prior information you
            are charging.
            It is illegal you have not mentioned this type of deduction any where.

            Pleaseget back to me as soon as possible.else i have to close all service which i am taking from HDFC UNWILLINGLY

            I have loan from hdfc
            I have my salary account in hdfc
            I am using HDFC debit card
            I applied
            for Credit Card too..
            ",
            "from": {
                "id": "785918218185264",
                "name": "Arun Gupta",
                "picture": {
                    "data": {
                        "is_silhouette": false,
                        "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xlp1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/1725162_823511061092646_1294656835996703680_n.jpg?oh=81e21c67e4b01f6b60784749827090d3&oe=573FE3C5&__gda__=1462383820_126055db9c94eb67294e2d73d4d46dd3"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

Hope, this will help someone... :)